# Echo jQuery variable into PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I have this code to export an image:

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    var frontPlateClass = $('.choose-front-plate-size').find('a.active').parent().prop('className'),
    // alert(frontPlateClass);
});


$image = $_POST['plate_image'];
$ebay_username = $_POST['ebay_username'];
$decoded = base64_decode(str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $image));
$date = date('m-d-Y', time());
$name = $ebay_username."-front-" . $date .".png";
file_put_contents("/var/makeaplate.justapplications.co.uk/cart/" . $name, $decoded);
$full_path = "/var/wmakeaplate.justapplications.co.uk/cart/" . $name;
imageCreateCorners($full_path, $name, 25);
$name1 = 'cart/'.$name;
echo '<div class="content-btns">';
echo "<img src='$name1' alt='image' id='front_img' />";
echo '<p class="download-btn"><a href="download.php?ebay_username='.$ebay_username.'&img=' . $name1 .'">Download front plate</a></p>';
echo '</div>';
```

As you can see I have 1 jQuery variable `frontPlateClass`. 
How can I add this in php with echo?

Comment: PHP runs on the server to create the HTML/JavaScript for the browser to run later.  What are you trying to do, exactly?

Comment: I want to have the classname into exported image name, like:   "classname-image.png"

Comment: always php codes executes first, if you want to access the variable (which is not php) then you have use AJAX or using FORMS....

Comment: Also base on your code, look like you tryng do modify an image with php. You should take a look to canvas. Some plugin exist to do exactly what you want to acheive. That will place the work on your web user browser instead of in your web server

Comment: @ferozakbar I guess we do not really need html in this specific case

Comment: in form we can simply assign this CLASS VALUE to a hidden field,so we  can pass it easily,so thats why i asked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Develop following structure;

**function.php**

```
<?php
    $frontPlateClass = $_POST["frontPlateClass"];
    // Now you can use this vaiable anywhere you want
    $image = $_POST['plate_image'];
    $ebay_username = $_POST['ebay_username'];
    $decoded = base64_decode(str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $image));
    $date = date('m-d-Y', time());
    $name = $ebay_username."-front-" . $date .".png";
    file_put_contents("/var/makeaplate.justapplications.co.uk/cart/" . $name, $decoded);
    $full_path = "/var/wmakeaplate.justapplications.co.uk/cart/" . $name;
    imageCreateCorners($full_path, $name, 25);
    ........
?>
```

In your html:

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    var frontPlateClass = $('.choose-front-plate-size').find('a.active').parent().prop('className'),
    $.ajax({
       url: "path_to_function.php",
       method: "POST",
       data: "frontPlateClass=" + frontPlateClass,
      success: function(response) {} 
    });
});
```

By doing this, you can send js variable to php. And you can use that value in php side

Answer (score 0):

PHP is executed before there is content on the screen, at the server. jQuery / HTML is rendered by the browser once the page is sent to the client.

The only way you can do this (passing a JS variable to PHP) is by doing an AJAX call to a PHP file after the document has loaded, sending the variable as the data.

Answer (score 0):

You cant do it like that.

One thing that you have to know, it the difference between server side and client side.

Server side generate the html, the javascript etc... Php is executed on the server side.

Client side come after, it receive all html/javascript/etc... generate through the server. Once it receive all this text, browser have mechanisms to parse the javascript and execute it.

The solution for your problem:

You can use ajax, it gonna create a request to a php script on the server side. Ajax is generated from the client side. So you will be able to send the content of frontPlateClass to a php script.

Comment: Also I suggest you mark this question as resolve, if you have ajax question, make sure that this question is not already asked, if not, Create another ajax specific question.

Answer (score 0):

You can't 'echo' it using PHP. I would add a blank div using HTML in your PHP code and then have JQuery populate it.

So in your HTML something like this..

```
<div class="inner">Goodbye</div>
```

Then in your script something like this.

```
$( ".inner" ).append( frontPlateClass );
```

Hope this puts you in the right direction.